# Is there a way in Unity to get the voice language of the operating system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using voice commands in unity, and I would like to know the way to get the speech language of my operating system, since from what I checked it may be different from the language that is obtained with Application.systemLanguage. Is there a way?

I try to use Application.systemLanguage but the speech language can be diferent.

Comment: I wonder how often such situation happens. Is it really worth to spend time on?

Comment: What OS? Does it have native APIs to get the speech language?

Comment: @shingo the OS is Windows 10, I'm kind of new to this, I don't know if it has native APIs to get the speech language. How can I know that? Im using KeywordRecognizer

Comment: Why not let the user select the language before playing?

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/voice-input#languages) says that _speech commands will always run in the system's display language_, so it seems like it should be consistent with Application.systemLanguage.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov But for the voice commands, I would like from unity to know what voice language it has in the OS so that depending on the language, put the commands in one language or another

Comment: In UWP you could go through [SpeechRecognizer.SystemSpeechLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognizer.systemspeechlanguage?view=winrt-22621) ... you could also dig your way through the [Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.8) as a last resort

Comment: @shingo That page talks about voice commands for Hololens 2, my project is used on normal PC with windows 10, without hololens.

Comment: @derHugo I'm pretty new in this, I don't know how to make a UWP for unity. It is very difficult?

Comment: UWP is deprecated, users shouldn't build new things in it.

Comment: @Miguel "*I try to use Application.systemLanguage but the speech language can be diferent.*"I think the concern here is unnecessary. It should be the same, and just in case, the best practice is probably what Alexey said, which is to prompt the user at the start of your application to choose a language.